# React compile failing for Wordpress Gutenberg block

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I've started with

`npx @wordpress/create-block@latest my-block --variant=dynamic`

which goes as far as "installing @wordpress/scripts package" and then fails with SIGKILL and no action on my part.  If I manually install @wordpress/scripts then npm start will die when I attempt to compile the boilerplate provided by create-block.

What other info can I provide and/or how can I troubleshoot this?

Error log from `npx @wordpress/create-block...`

```
Error: Command was killed with SIGKILL (Forced termination): npm install @wordpress/scripts --save-dev
    at makeError (/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/node_modules/execa/lib/error.js:59:11)
    at handlePromise (/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/node_modules/execa/index.js:114:26)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async module.exports (/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/node_modules/@wordpress/create-block/lib/init-wp-scripts.js:19:2)
    at async module.exports (/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/node_modules/@wordpress/create-block/lib/scaffold.js:151:4)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/node_modules/@wordpress/create-block/lib/index.js:120:6) {
  shortMessage: 'Command was killed with SIGKILL (Forced termination): npm install @wordpress/scripts --save-dev',
  command: 'npm install @wordpress/scripts --save-dev',
  exitCode: undefined,
  signal: 'SIGKILL',
  signalDescription: 'Forced termination',
  stdout: '',
  stderr: '',
  failed: true,
  timedOut: false,
  isCanceled: false,
  killed: false
}

Node.js v20.10.0
```

`